# TensorFlow - how to serialize and send Status to remote

Tags: tensorflow

I am writing a distributed rendezvous implementation.

**Requester** - requests a tensor.

**Responder** - looks the tensor up and sends it to the requester.

If an error occurs on the responder side, I would like to send the error code to the requester which will propagate it to upper levels.

I saw that on GRPC the Status is converted to a `::grpc::status`. Is that enough for Status serialization (i.e. can I simply mem-copy the `::grpc::status` bytes inside my message body and send it, or is there another call required to flatten the data)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems clear that I can't mem-copy the `::grpc::status` directly because it has the `error_message` and `error_details` fields of type `::grpc::string` which is basically a typedef of `std::string`. So the data is not flat as far as I know, nor can I count on it.

I couldn't find a code example of how the serialization is done, so I did the following:

1. Create a Proto object with 3 fields: `error_code`, `error_message`, `error_details`.
2. When serializing, I would set those fields manually from the `::grpc::status` and then call `proto.SerializeToArray()`.
3. When deserializing, `ParseProtoUnlimited(&proto)` and then create a `::grpc::status` from the proto fields.

Seems clean enough. Maybe just a little code duplication.

**Proto:**

```
message ErrorStatusProto {
  int32 error_code = 1;
  string error_message = 2;
  string error_details = 3;
}
```

**Serialize:**

```
::grpc::Status gs = ToGrpcStatus(rm.status_);
ErrorStatusProto gsProto;
gsProto.set_error_code(gs.error_code());
gsProto.set_error_message(gs.error_message());
gsProto.set_error_details(gs.error_details());
gsProto.SerializeToArray(&message[kErrorStatusStartIndex],
                         gsProto.ByteSize());
if (gsProto.ByteSize() > kErrorStatusMaxSize) {
  LOG(ERROR) << "Error status (" << gsProto.ByteSize() << " bytes) "
             << "is too big to fit in RDMA message ("
             << kErrorStatusMaxSize << " bytes). Truncated.";
}
```

**Deserialize:**

```
ErrorStatusProto gsProto;
CHECK(ParseProtoUnlimited(
    &gsProto, &message[kErrorStatusStartIndex], kErrorStatusMaxSize))
    << "Failed to parse error status proto from message. Aborting.";
::grpc::Status gs((::grpc::StatusCode)gsProto.error_code(), 
                  gsProto.error_message(), gsProto.error_details());
rm.status_ = FromGrpcStatus(gs);
```